# Tomcat 9.0.16 : Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, tomcat9

Recently I have downloaded JDK 11.0.2 & Tomcat 9.0.16 and set the environment variables, but whenever I am starting the tomcat it is showing the following exception in the console and http://localhost:8080/ is not accessible.
Please help.

```
    06-Mar-2019 03:34:43.186 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]] org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1055)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:612)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:295)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:54)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.close(NioSelectorPool.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:338)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1090)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1098)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:557)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 29 more
```

I also tried with different connector ports but did not worked, but when i tried same thing with same configuration in another machine it worked without exception and localhost was accessible. Is there any problem with my machine.

Comment: You could give it a try and add: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true (setenv.sh or setenv.bat). Does your machine have certain firewall rules that prevent a proper tomcat start?

Comment: Thanks @AndreAlbert I tried by adding _JAVA_OPTIONS in environment variable with value -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true but it worked for -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 7):

***This mistake means that your port is busy***.

1. Stop Tomcat
2. Change the port number
3. Restart your app

[Read more about the mistake here](http://www.tutorialbyexample.com/2016/03/apache-tomcat-error-and-solution-BindException-LifecycleException.html)

Comment: the link is down

Comment: Oh sorry to hear that. I don't remember the source anymore. However, you can just try the steps above. It should help